# Conditional expectation of X given X+Y

Tags: distributions, conditional-expectation, convolution

X and Y are two independent variables, X ~ exp(a), Y ~ exp(a). I need to find E(X|X+Y). I tried to calculate by definition, but it did not lead to success. Maybe there is another, more convenient way to do it?

Comment: Hm, thanks  so E(X|Z) = 1/a * 1/z?

Comment: That is incorrect.  You were given the exact solution...

Comment: This has appeared several times on our site, but I cannot immediately find it.  Note that since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, $$2E[X\mid X+Y]=E[X\mid X+Y] + E[Y\mid X+Y]=E[X+Y|\mid X+Y]=X+Y$$ implies $E[X\mid X+Y]=(X+Y)/2.$